# How to add arrow on the right side of jQuery accordion menu

Tags: css, jquery-ui

The title is a little bit confusing since accordion menu already has an arrow which toggles on select/deselect but what I mean is this - right now when I have selected menu it looks like this :

[image: No arrow]

and  what I want to make it look like this:

[image: With arrow]

So it's not the arrow on the right side but inside the menu, it's the arrow right after the right border.

I'm using the standard jQuery accordion and the menus are created like this :

```
@foreach (...)
{ 
  <h3>@item.Name</h3>
    <div>
      <ul>
        @foreach (...)
       </ul>
    </div>
}
```

So basically I'm using the standard structure of the accordion menu it's just that the menu is created dynamically. The custom styles that make the background blue when a certain menu is selected looks like this:

```
.ui-state-active,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-active,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-active {
border-bottom: 1px solid #363636;
background: #ffffff url(../Content/images/..) 50% 50% repeat-x;
font-weight: normal;
color: #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #000000;
}
```

I'm not sure but I think this is the appropriate place to add the style for showing this additional arrow I just don't know how to do it. Also, even though the style is a little customized it's still the original `jquery.ui.smoothness.css` so I'm open to suggestions how to show this arrow. The easiest solutions seems to change the `background` but I would prefer to not touch since it's not my code and just find a way to add the arrow independent from the `background` styling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pseudo elements.

With pseudo elements, also known as `:before` and `:before` you can create extra content, without added extra HTML code.

**HTML**

```
<div><span class="arrow"></span></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    width: 120px;
    height: 60px;
    position: relative;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #09438d, #0258a8);
}

div:before { /* The blue arrow at the right of the menu */
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -20px;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto 0;
    border: 10px solid;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #064d9a;
}

.arrow { /* The circle inside the menu */
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,1), 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto 0;
}

.arrow:before { /* The white arrow inside the circle */
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    top: 5px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    border: 5px solid;
    border-color: #FFF transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

### Explanations:

**The Blue Arrow:**

Here we are creating a new element with `:before`. We are setting the `position` to `absolute` so our arrow can be placed exactly where we want it to be.

To create the arrow we are using borders. In this way we don't have to use an image.

To do the arrow effect, we then add a border on our `:before`-element. Now we just have to color our arrow.

This is done by only adding color to one of the border's sides, and `transparent`to the others.
*(See image below:)*

[image]

To place the arrow in middle vertical we are setting the `top` and `bottom` to `0` and then the `margin` to `auto`. Now we can align our arrow in the same way as we can align `block` elements. To move it out of the menu-box we simply just set the `right` to `-20px`*(The double width of our arrow)*.

**The White Arrow:**

This is very much in the same way as The Blue Arrow.
Here we just create a circle first and add or arrow to that instead of the menu-box.

[Here's a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k35Xa/1/)

Answer (score 1):

First add `position: relative` to the .ui-widget-header class.

Second add a new pseudo selector for the .ui-widget-header:

```
ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header:after {
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    //Trick here - drawing a triangle with border
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left-color: red;
    //Next positioning it correctly
    position: absolute;
    right: -20px; 
    top: 50%; //Center it in the middle
    margin-top: -10px; //And pull it back 10px (Half of the triangles height)
}
```

Comment: And I was too slow :D

Comment: Yeah, but thanks for the effort and the comments, I really didn't know that one can make a triangle like this.